# Which test should I use to compare means for two independent binomial samples?

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, binary-data, proportion

I am trying to compare the number of "likes" on social media posts between two independent samples of about $n=60$ each.  Is it appropriate to use a *chi-squared test* for this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Here is a quick simulation:

```
          Medication
Vote      Group A   Group B   Totals
  Like         15      34       49
  Dislike      50      27       77
  Totals       65      61      126
```

Running a chi-square:

```
prop.test(Likes, correct = F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  Likes
X-squared = 14.1247, df = 1, p-value = 0.0001711
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.5105958 -0.1758606
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.3061224 0.6493506
```

Alternatively, you can also run a Fisher's exact test:

```
    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  Likes
p-value = 0.0002326
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1023803 0.5463718
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.2411957
```